# JunitReport - report format and styledir not working

Tags: junit

I have placed the build.xml file in the same folder as my test script it does produce the xml file after I ran the code but I want the report in html so I have amended the report format to 'frames' and added the style directory but it doesn't work it still just produce the xml file.

```
<property name="report.dir" value="test\reports" />
<target name="generateReport">
<junitreport todir="${report.dir}">
  <fileset dir="${report.dir}">
    <include name="*.xml" />
  </fileset>`
  <report format="frames" styledir="C:\TestFolder\junit-frames.xsl" todir="./report/html" />
 </junitreport>
 </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`styledir` parameter must point at the xsl directory, not the single file.

Comment: Thanks could you please tell me what I need to download that include the junit-frames? because I only downloaded the junit frames file.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to specify XSL files if you don't want to customize them. Read the documentation in https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html

Comment: Thank you pointing to the directory worked. I did missed one step I didn't run from ANT that's why is not generating the html.